# Application to download subtitles as text?

Tags: text, movie, subtitle, television

I'm working on a side project where I am searching through television and movie shows for phrases and words. I am wondering is there an app that will grab subtitles for a show / series / movie(s) and make sure they are in txt format?

I would like to start a rip for a television show / movie by name and get a text file of the subtitles for each episode.

Is this an option?

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly the same this using this open source project developed by me. https://github.com/atulgpt/SubtitleDownloader.git It also supports batch mode, recursive folder search and two different database. And for better results it uses hash of a video file. If found useful give a star to the project and up-vote this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your source media is, but assuming you're working from video discs, *ffmpeg* can be used to extract subtitles. The command would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/some/file -an -vn -c:s:1 srt sub1.srt
```

which means extract from some/file ignore audio, ignore video, and extract subtitles from the first stream. You can use ffmpeg to analyze the streams as well.

It will extract to a srt file which is a human readable text format